# Installed Ubuntu 15.10, need help fixing pam_kwallet errors preventing me from logging in

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display, kwallet

History so far:

- Attempted one install, fought with video drivers for hours, and then I ran into an error while logging in again `/lib/security/pam_kwallet5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"`.  Decided to do a fresh reinstall and try again.
- Reinstalled Ubuntu 15.10.  Typed in my password.  I was logged in and presented with a blank screen with the default Ubuntu password.  `/var/log/auth.log` gives me the same pam_kwallet5.so error messages.
- I dropped to a console, did a `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`. I also did an `apt-get install nvidia-352`.  Then I rebooted.
- Presented with a login screen, display drivers seem to be in place as it's snappy fast graphically.  Log in, hear error sound, returns me to the login screen.  I check auth.log, and it still says `/lib/security/pam_kwallet5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.`

Now I'm stuck.  I've been at this thing for hours, I just want to install Ubuntu and log in with working graphical drivers.

Edit: See below, it seems this is due to installing nvidia-35* from a popular third party repository.

Comment: Attempting to get the pam_kwallet5.so file this way didn't work:  apt-get install kwalletmanager pam-kwallet5

Comment: The plot thickens.  The errors want to find both pam_kwallet.so and pam_kwallet5.so.  Turns out I have had the latter file, pam_kwallet5.so.  But the former file pam_kwallet.so is missing.

My pam_kwallet5.so is located in /lib/x86_64-linux-gpu/security, while the error message is looking for it in /lib/security.  So I did: sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gpu/security /lib/security.  That took care of some of the error messages, but now I'm hung up on some NetworkManager error message?  Overall this is definitely a Ubuntu bug, I did a plain straightforward install and got this.

Comment: The two remaining errors in auth.log are:  "Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out.  That's a bluetooth error, I don't need bluetooth, so I removed that with sudo systemctl disable bluetooth.service

Also "Rejected send message, 10 matched rules; (lots of stuff) /usr/sbin/dnsmasq (lots of stuff) /usr/sbin/NetworkManager...  And in syslog, I see "dnsmasq owner not found on bus: Could not get owner of name 'org.freedesktop/NetworkManager.dnsmasq': no such name  I can't seem to fix this one...going to start over for a third reinstall...

Comment: Final update.  A third reinstall got me further.  Only changes I made were to put the root partition before the swap and make the root primary (it's a dual boot system, Windows has another primary).  I also set it to auto log in, I didn't want to deal with that issue.  As for display driver issue, it seems Ubuntu 15.10/linux kernel 4.2 is in between nouveau and intel display fixes.  For now, I had to get the intel devices loaded from instructions here: http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=intel-skl-prelim-support  and I manually installed my own nvidia drivers.

Comment: It's good, that you try to investigate your own issue. However, please [edit] your question, when you want to add information. Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) are much more readable there and overall it's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Give me a ping and I'll upvote your question, once you added the new info.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to installing Nvidia 3.52/3.55/3.58 drivers from the ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa.  It seems they can install the drivers, but it messes with something with Xorg, causing it to have the errors described above.  When I remove any of those driver packages, the problem goes away.